# How to Improve Magento Search

Tags: search, catalogsearch

I would like to know if there is an option in the backend where I write the name of a product in the search and it shows me in mini images the products with that name before I search, or would it have to be by module? Could someone give me a light? If it is by module what files I will need to create it

Comment: It's to us to guess your Magento version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.9% certain this is not possible in the backend.  I use the Template Master Ajax Search module ($29) which does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Is that I am intern in a company and are trying to leave the paid modules doing some customized, I will do a lot of research and try to do, because if you have some payments that make it possible to create, thanks for the help